# How to create a second webroot folder for a second-level domain in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to create a second webroot in nginx?

I've got over 60 GB of pictures. I think store them in another folder and use a 2nd-level domain like pic.domain.com  will make managing them more convenient.

By the way, my sites is running on a windows server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a separate

```
server {
  server_name sub.domain.com;
  root /your/image/root;
  # other options
}
```

Comment: Only when I append another port rather than the default 90 to the domain name the server could reach the image dir.Is there any way to deal with this? Just use img.domain.com:8000 instead of img.domain.com?

Comment: Well, I fixed it just simply by not specifying a listening port. Thank you.